# Illustrator Anchor Point Tool Not Found

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to Illustrator and i'm learning using video courses in which the tutor uses anchor point tool to make a straight line curved i cannot find it can anyone help it is of ^ this shape Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html

Comment: Welcome Eswarachandra! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding  basic software education. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try long-clicking on the pen tool and you will have like some kind of a drop down that will help you choose the " > " tool you are searching for.
Or hold shift + C and you will get it.

I hope this is what you are asking for :)

Comment: Hi Leila, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!